# Creating a new object in Typescript is giving an error that it requires an extra comma

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following classes:

```
export class datalist
{
    data: mydata[];
}

export class mydata
{
    data1: string;
    data2: string;
}
```

I'm trying to create these types using the following syntax:

```
const mydatalist: datalist = {
  ...new datalist(),
  data: this.somedata.map(function(x, i) {
    return {          
      data1: x.somedata1, 
      data2: x.somedata2 
    };
  }
};
```

However, I get the following error:

> ',' expected

Please could someone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not closing your map() function.

```
const mydatalist: datalist = {
  ...new datalist(),
  data: this.somedata.map(function(x, i) {
    return {          
      data1: x.somedata1, 
      data2: x.somedata2 
    };
  })   <<-- here
};
```

Comment: We have a specific close reason for typos. Please vote to close using that rather than answering. You can tell the OP what's wrong in a comment.

Comment: Thankyou for your help @Christoph Lütjen